# Flutter Caching

Tags: caching, flutter

How to save network data in cash and then implement it have any resource or example, I use flutter_cashe_manager but I can't implement it in my code

there I call the API API return data and save it in cash, whene i call this future method its returns the list from the cache JSON file.. this is the code where return the data list from the cache.

```
TopicHab _topicHab;
  Future<List<Topic>> fetchTopicList(String api) async {
    try {
//      var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url+api);
      var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url+api);
      print('files ${file.readAsStringSync()}');
      print('files ${file.path}');
//      var tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
//      String tempPath = tempDir.path;
//      print('path ${tempPath}');
      _topicHab = TopicHab.fromJson(jsonDecode(file.readAsStringSync()));
      print('Topic Length ${_topicHab.cats.length}');
      return _topicHab.cats;
    } catch (e) {
      return List<Topic>();
    }
  }
```

their whare the snapshot.haseData is false but its use streamside first time its work but next time it does not work. I can't find what the proper problems

```
drawer: Drawer(
          child: Container(
            color: drawerBackgroundColors,
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: newsBloc.allTopic,
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Topic>> snapshot) {
                print('newsBloc.allTopic ${newsBloc.allTopic}' );
                print('snapshot data ${snapshot.hasData}');
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  print('snapshot topic ${snapshot.data.length}');
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: childMenuBackgroundColor,
                          border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )
                          ),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                        height: 50,
                        child: ListTile(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => TopicsNewsScreen(
                                        parentTopic: true,
                                          topicId: snapshot.data[index].topicId,
                                          topicName: snapshot
                                              .data[index].topicName
                                              .toUpperCase())));
                            },
                            title: Text(
                              snapshot.data[index].topicName,
                              style: childMenuStyle,
                            ))
                      );
                    },
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The package used is Hive

Another way of caching is by using hive a No-SQL database it is faster to retrieve documents and is easy to use. And it retrieves data faster

For more details check:https://github.com/shashiben/Anime-details to know how to cache using hive from rest api